# Dynamic inheritance of properties in Maven

Tags: maven, inheritance, gmaven-plugin

I wonder what is a conventional approach to passing information from parent to child module in a dynamic way in Maven.

There is property inheritance which works fine but is static in nature. Properties get inherited by child module before any lifecycle phase is activated in parent module and further changes made to them are not propagated. As far as I understand, this behavior is by design.

My goal is to make some computations in parent module once and then pass the result to child modules. I would like to avoid repeating same actions in each of the child modules since they are time-consuming. To be more precise, I am using GMaven plugin to make computations using Groovy.

I know there is MavenSession which probably allows passing information across multi-module project, but can it be used without writing my own plugin?

Answer (score 0):

They usually do this by sharing object in FS between the plugins, this seems to be the most Maven way however imperfect this sound. The problem with `MavenSession` is that is allows strings only.

With GMaven if you're running via a script you could try creating a dummy plugin containing a single static `ConcurrentHashMap` to store the shared state and then access it inside your Groovy script.

I would however stay with the traditional approach, but things might have became better with GMaven as I haven't touched it for two years.